# Error notification on plone 4

Tags: plone, zope

I just want to have email notification when an error is declared in plone 4.

Any ideas of product or any "how-to" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can easily configure the built-in email notification for Zope, but we found that adding the [mailinglogger](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mailinglogger) package makes the emails a lot more managable.

The package adds:

- customisable and dynamic subject lines for emails sent
- emails sent with configurable headers for easy filtering
- flood protection to ensure the number of emails sent is not excessive
- support for SMTP servers that require authentication
- configurable log entry filtering

The `plone.recipe.zope2instance` buildout recipe supports mailinglogger out of the box; simply define a `mailinglogger` variable in your `[instance]` part and include the mailinglogger egg:

```
[instance]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
eggs +=
    mailinglogger
# Other options go here
mailinglogger =
  <mailing-logger>
    level warning
    flood-level 100000
    smtp-server localhost
    from logger@example.com
    to error-receiver@example.com
    subject [ServerName Error] [%(hostname)s] %(levelname)s - %(line)s
  </mailing-logger>
```

The package has been invaluable for us on larger clusters, where we configure additional variables per instance to be included in the subject; we can see what instance the problem occurred on directly in the subject.

Comment: Apparently just add more to fields

Comment: Apparently the example above is wrong and the level is ignored (should go outside the <mailing-logger> tag

Comment: No, the level can be specified for both the whole logger and for individual log handling sections such as `<mailing-logger>`. We use the exact syntax in my example in production right now, only the configured values differ.

Answer (score 4):

Configuring mailing-logger is documented at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.zope2instance but I think that email log notification is built into recent Zope2 releases, so you should now add the following to you `[instance]` section:

```
event-log-custom =
  <email-notifier>
    from server@here.com
    to kdie@localhost
    subject "anything goes here"
    smtp-server 127.0.0.1
  </email-notifier>
```

(example from http://myzope.kedai.com.my/blogs/kedai/44)

Comment: I tried this my log files disappeared - they're no longer in var/log

Comment: @scarba05: See another answer on this question, where the logfile is preserved: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7832569/100297

Answer (score 3):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.logbook is handy too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an email-notifier to your event-log-custom in buildout.cfg.  Unfortunately there's no way to append it to your existing logging configuration but the following will mimic what plone.recipe.zope2instance does for the event log anyway

```
event-log-custom =
  <logfile>
    path ${buildout:directory}/var/log/${:_buildout_section_name_}.log
    level INFO
  </logfile>
  <email-notifier>
    from server@here.com
    to admin@company.com
    subject "[Zope alert - ${:_buildout_section_name_}]"
    smtp-server localhost
    level error
  </email-notifier>
```